# characteristic of an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

I just recently took some light reading to refresh my memory on Abstract algebra and came across some doubts I had not cleared before.
This question was posted by me before (possibly, poorly worded then)
and while I was directed to an existing thread, the thread did not satisfy my doubts.
This could be a good time to have my doubts addressed.

> Theorem: The characteristic of an integral domain is $0$ or a prime number.
>
> Proof: By author.
>
> Suppose that the unity $1$ has order integer $n$ and that $n=st$ where $1\leq s, t\leq n$.

What is the motivation for which we have the defined inequality $"1\leq s, t\leq n"$?

Then,

> $0=n\cdot 1=\left ( st \right ) \cdot 1=\left ( s\cdot 1 \right ) \left ( t\cdot 1 \right )$.

The above is clear.

> So, $s\cdot 1 =0$ or $t\cdot 1=0$.

The above is clear.

> Since $n$ is the least positive integer with the property that $n \cdot 1=0$, we must have $s=n$ or $t=n$.
> Thus $n$ is prime.

It is not clear at all how the above relates to $n$ being prime.

Comment: Defining $n$ as the characteristic of the integral domain in question (assuming it's not $0$), proving it is prime requires proving that any divisor is $1$ or $n$. Therefore he assumes $n$ has divisor $s$, with $st = n$. Now such divisors necessarily have $1\leq s,t\leq n$. He then goes on to prove $s=1$ or $n$. Since $s$ is any divisor, this shows $n$ is prime

Comment: What about the part where he made the claim that it could be t=n?@Max

Comment: That corresponds to the possibility $s=1$.

Comment: It is shown for positive integers $s,t$ that $n=st\implies\{s,t\}=\{1,n\}$. That can only be true if $n$ is a prime. If e.g. $n=6$ then $\{s,t\}=\{2,3\}$ would also be a possibility.